# Parsing out multiple numbers numbers from a text column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a column of type nvarchar that displays the sizes of different pipes.
Here is a condensed example for practical purposes:

| Sizes |
| --- |
| 9.25" x 6mm |
| 9.5" x 6mm |
| 10.25" x 6mm |
| 23.25" 6mm |
| 8" x 6mm w/pullstrap |
| 13.7" x 6mm to 8mm |

I'm tasked with ordering these sizes from smallest to largest. My idea was to parse out the first and second number, cast them to floats, and multiply them together placing the result in an adjacent column and use that to `ORDER BY`. However, I run into an issue when trying to parse out the second number because the data was input differently on some sizes. Is there a way to successfully parse out the second number, or am I approaching this task the wrong way?

Comment: The real problem is the data here, let's be honest. Really you should be storing the 2 dimensions, and the scale used, in different columns. Considering you are using both inches and millimetres, that would mean storing the data in 4 separate columns, and then having another table that has the multiplier for converting one scale to another (or all to metric, perhaps).

Comment: Then again, you also have `6mm to 8mm` as a value, so perhaps you need 6 columns; a min and max for the *x* and *y* dimensions, and then the scale of those min and max values.

Comment: Might be best to give a concrete code example to show why your parse is failing on the second number, and maybe someone could help you with that, but overall I agree with @Larnu, if your data isn't consistent enough to parse numbers, I don't think there's any way you can order them other than just by that first number, unfortunately.

Comment: Assuming you can't change the input side and restrict / massage the data on the way in, you can in theory parse all this. But it's going to be a lot easier in a programming language (during runtime, not in SQL) and you're going to have to know all the ways the data can be weird because you'll have to include those scenarios in your regex strategy.

Comment: ...If it's a crazy amount of records (can't do it during runtime) you can also write something in a programming language that you run once, it does the logic and updates the records.

Answer (score 0):

Since almost all the rows have 6mm in common then it's safe to say that first part of the values are enough to sort the data. Please have a look:

```
 create table yourtable (Sizes nvarchar(200));
 insert into yourtable values('9.25" x 6mm');
 insert into yourtable values('9.5" x 6mm');
 insert into yourtable values('10.25" x 6mm');
 insert into yourtable values('23.25" 6mm');
 insert into yourtable values('8" x 6mm w/pullstrap');
 insert into yourtable values('13.7" x 6mm to 8mm');
```

Query:

```
 select Sizes from yourtable
 order by cast(left(Sizes,charindex('"',Sizes)-1) as float) desc
```

Output:

| Sizes |
| --- |
| 23.25" 6mm |
| 13.7" x 6mm to 8mm |
| 10.25" x 6mm |
| 9.5" x 6mm |
| 9.25" x 6mm |
| 8" x 6mm w/pullstrap |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad908cf0a650d403ae036ccb2765c116)*

Comment: My apologies, I should've elaborated more and paid more attention to the detail I put in the column. All of the rows do not have 6mm in common in the actual dataset. They all vary. I attempted a similar approach to yours only to find that even through the rows were in the correct order based on inches, they were out of order when looking at the mm. Hence, why I am attempting to parse both values out and multiply them together.